# SQL update query on join table

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE 
    t1
SET 
    t1.c3 = t2.c3,
    t1.c4 = t1.c4 
FROM 
    t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
WHERE 
    t1.c5 = 'In Progrss'
```

I want to update value from top row of table t2.

For example in t2 table having 3 rows with criteria match above only top row value `update in t1 table(ROW ID 3 VALUES TO UPDATE IN t1 table)`.

**t2 table:**

```
id  c1      c2     c3     c4
-----------------------------
1   ABC     XYZ    280    300
2   ABC     XYZ    290    400
3   ABC     XYZ    310    500
4   PQR     STR    210    400
```

**t1 table:**

```
id  c1      c2     c3     c4   c5
----------------------------------
1   ABC     XYZ                In Progrss
5   ABC     XYZ                In Progrss
8   ABC     XYZ                In Progrss
15  PQR     STR                IN Progress
```

Comment: which DBMS do you use?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Postgres’ update/join syntax goes like:

```
update t1
set c3 = t2.c3, c4 = t1.c4
from t2
where 
    t1.c1 = t2.c1 
    and t1.c2 = t2.c2
    and t1.c5 = 'In Progress'
```

If there are several matching rows in `t2` and you want the one with the smallest `id`, then you can use `row_number()` in a subquery:

```
update t1
set c3 = t2.c3, c4 = t1.c4
from (select t2.*, row_number() over(partition by c1, c2 order by id) rn from t2) t2
where 
    t1.c1 = t2.c1 
    and t1.c2 = t2.c2
    and t1.c5 = 'In Progress'
    and t2.rn = 1
```

Comment: thnks for quick reply, your query will update 310, 500 in t1 all rows?

Comment: is there any solution on it?

Comment: @Bhushan: I updated my answer with another query that selects the first matching row. Il will update 280, 300 for all three rows in  `t1`.

Comment: @Bhushan: are you actually using Postgres? I thought I saw that informatio in your question, but now I don't.

Comment: i want heighest row id and i dont know the row id in real scenario, updated table in original post